# How to stop slider when .mp4 video is played in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, video, html5-video, bxslider

i'm using **"bxlider.js"** plugin to slide 1 **"Html<>"** video and 2 image in my MVC project. My problem is when i'm playing a video, the slider is still sliding.

Here is my code:

```js
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true,
        });
```

```html
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <video id="HomePageVdo" height="210" controls="controls" >
      <source class="video-width" src="~/Media/HomePageVdo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="~/Media/Sample1.png" role="img" width="350" height="210" alt="Sample1" title="Sample1"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="~/Media/Sample2.jpg" role="img" width="350" height="210" alt="Sample2" title="Sample2"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please need help... any other plugin van help
Thanks.!!!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Finally got the solution..***

```
        var videoID = document.getElementById('HomePageVdo');

        var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true,
        });

        videoID.addEventListener("play", function () {
            slider.stopAuto();
        });

        videoID.addEventListener("pause", function () {
            slider.startAuto();
        });

        videoID.addEventListener("end", function () {
            slider.startAuto();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :--

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
               auto: true,
               autoControls: true,
             });
```

and where ever you want to stop `bxslider` use `slider.stopShow();` and when to start use `slider.startShow();` as shown below :-

```
$("#HomePageVdo").on("pause", function (e) {
   slider.startShow();
});

$("#HomePageVdo").on("play", function (e) {
   slider.stopShow();
});
```

Comment: i want to stop the slider on play & playing of video. and when video is paused or ended playing,, the slider should again start sliding.. so what will be code for that..

Comment: but how to stop slider slides when video is played or playing  and resume sliding when video is paused..???

Comment: @swapnilnax....sorry but i will not provide you full fledge working code...as per your question this answer is more than enough...just try to use this code along with your skills and your problem will solve....

Comment: i tried with html video events.. but its not working

like : .onplay, .onpause ,.onended, .onplaying

Comment: ReferenceError: slider is not defined
 
slider.stopShow();

Comment: @swapnilnax....where you are intializing bxslider give it a name slider as shown in my answer..

Comment: it will work just check your code carefully...it should match the code written here.@swapnilnax

Comment: TypeError: slider.stopShow() is not a function
 
slider.stopShow();